# Prompt User in ArcGIS Pro Attribute Rules

Tags: arcgis-pro, null, attribute-rules

In Attribute Assistant I have some prompts for the user to enter a value. Sometimes these fields do not have value and the field can be null. Attribute Rules don't have a prompt methodology. I am using the validation rule to alert the user that there are fields that need to be populated.

Here is the code:

```
if (IsEmpty($feature.field name))
   return false
else if ($feature.HNS==null)
   return true
```

Is there a way to add a try/except or a statement that it can be null if a value isn't entered?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're asking for, but it seems like you have several options.  Would using multiple "if" statements, a "when" statement,  or an "or" operator would work for you?  Check out the [logical functions documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/logic/).

I'm just not sure why you're validating the field at all if you are fine with the value being null... are you only concerned about empty strings?  In that case, I would only check for that i.e.

```
if($feature.HNS == '') {
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zack.